# Get hardware information of /dev/video0

Tags: c++, linux, camera, usb

I have two USB camera in Linux, so i have two entries in `/dev/` directory(`video0` and `video1`).

I want to get hardware information (i.e. vendor id, product id, device name) about this two camera base on videoX and choose right camera depend on its hardware information.

is there any way to get hardware information about videoX in cpp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's easy by just traversing sysfs devices by a given class. The following command-line:

```
cat /sys/class/video4linux/video0/name 
cat /sys/class/video4linux/video0/device/input/input3/id/product
cat /sys/class/video4linux/video0/device/input/input3/id/vendor
```

Comment: Note that it is not always called `input35`